# Ubuntu desktop unable to mount share

Tags: mount, fstab, sharing

I've got a new installation of ubuntu running as a VM on server 2012. I've joined it to the domain using likewise open. I am able to use domain accounts to logon to the ubuntu desktop.

I am having a problem mounting or connecting to the windows server however. I've tried using "Connect to server" to get to the share but I get an error

> "please verify your credentials".

I've tried manually mounting the share using cifs, similar error

> `mount error(13) permission denied`

I've used the same credentials I used to log in as well as the administrator credentials to mount this share. I have an installation of ubuntu server which was able to mount the share without a problem, using the same methods. The only difference is the server is not joined to the domain. I can ping the server and the domain.

The entry in `fstab` looks like this:

`//SERVER-1/Music    /mnt/music    cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Have you installed `cifs-utils` as suggested in [this Ubuntu Wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)?

Comment: yes I did, I get output that mount.cifs is giving the error

Comment: Though not recommended, put the credentials in the `fstab` entry rather than using the hash. Also, it could be the domain that's mucking it up; perhaps adding the domain to the entry?

Comment: I've tried putting the credentials in the fstab file with the same results

Comment: I know that when I'm logging into our shares through AD at work that I have to use the domain as part of my username to authenticate: `domain\username` and the slash direction is important. Perhaps try that as part of your credential.

Comment: Used that as well in my password file: username=HOME\craig or username=craig + domain=HOME, Those didn't work either

Comment: Then I'd be looking at the access privileges on the domain controller.

Comment: the admin account for sure has access, I tried with these credentials too.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my FSTAB line to mount on my desktop computer a USB drive that is attached to a (remote) router.  Two points, you may need to identify the file system as "CIFS" and and you may need to include  "sec=ntlm".

```
#Mount Western Digital Passport Drive On Router
//rt-n56u/sda1 /media/My_Passport cifs rw,sec=ntlm,guest,uid=1000,gid=34,iocharset=utf8,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: I've tried many "sec=...." that i've found on the net. Either I would get a general error or the permission denied error stayed. What is the nofail for?

Comment: "nofail - Mount device when present but ignore if absent. This prevents errors being reported at boot for removable media." from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab

Comment: I finally found the Ubuntu page for the CIFS file system. Of course if you are not using CIFS, this would not apply. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/mount.cifs.8.html

Comment: Could you post the link for it?

Comment: Which link would you like?  Here is the one to: [Archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) for FSTAB. Finally figured out how to use the formatting.

Comment: So i read thru the page on mount.cifs and saw that you can specify kerberos auth. I tried this by adding sec=krb5 as stated in the man pages but I get operation not supported now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the other CIFS options.